# SQL Combine rows with same ID

Tags: php, t-sql

I have two tables and I need to combine the rows.

As far I have:

```
$sql = "SELECT A.AID, A.Street, B.FirstName, B.LastName                                     
        FROM A 
        LEFT JOIN B 
        ON A.AID = B.AID;";
```

Could you help me please to merge those rows, where several people live in the same street?

[image: Combine rows with INNER JOIN]

Comment: Might be simpler to do the merge in PHP, just sort the query by AID

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: I tagged my post with tsql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use GROUP BY to concatenate strings in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server)

Comment: The [`tsql`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/tsql/info) tag covers Sybase ASE and Microsoft SQL Server. Do you require a solution that works on both? Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Images of data bad, DDL and consumable data good, ... .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MySQL, then you would use `GROUP_CONCAT()` or a JSON aggregation function.  The idea is:

```
SELECT A.AID, A.Street,
       GROUP_CONCAT(B.FirstName, ' ', B.LastName SEPARATOR ', ') as names                                 
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B 
     ON A.AID = B.AID
GROUP BY A.AID, A.Street;
```

In SQL Server you would use `string_agg()`:

```
SELECT A.AID, A.Street,
       STRING_AGG(CONCAT(B.FirstName, ' ', B.LastName), ', ') as names                                 
FROM A LEFT JOIN
     B 
     ON A.AID = B.AID
GROUP BY A.AID, A.Street;
```